# c# Multiple values from a single textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, return-value, geography, coordinate

In C# I want to get multiple values from a single textbox. I want to develop an application that convert geographical coordinates frome latitude and longitude in other projection system. For example: The user enter following coordinat 41°24'12.2"N. The software will split and will assign to a = 41; b=24; c= 12.2; I mention that the b can be from 01 to 59 and can be writing in two forms choice by user, like: 41°05'12.2"N. or 41°5'12.2"N.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. 
Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? 
Show your effort first so people might show theirs. 
Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start..

Comment: How you suppose your users will enter °," and ' symbols in one textbox? Anyway you could easily parse textbox input with [RegExp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: The user will copy the coordinate frome Google Earth with ctrl+c and will paste in text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read more about string.substring and string.indexof method.
For more generic look for extension method in C#.

Here you have it:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/J66V5a

Answer (score 0):

You could use the textbox text to parse the data, but make sure you filter the input string as in:

```
if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != ':'|| e.KeyChar != '"' || e.KeyChar != '°' || e.KeyChar != ''')
{
         e.Handled = true;
}
```

Use the symbols as separators and split the string into 3:

```
    string ss = "41°24'12.2" + '"' + "N";
    string[] values = new string[3];
    char[] separators = new char[3] { '°',Convert.ToChar(0x27),Convert.ToChar(0x22)};

    values = ss.Split(separators);
```

The values you need are in the first 3 blocks of the "values" array as strings. Use the conversion class (`int a = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);`) to process the data.